# nginx lua, storing data across scripts without SQL?

Tags: nginx, lua

I'm wondering if there's a way to  store very large arrays across scripts. In my previous solution, I was using SQL to store this data, but with 200 requests to the page every second, that's a lot of unnecessary very large select queries!

I was thinking perhaps there might exist an nginx module out there in the wild that allows you to store data that can be easily modified and accessed through lua without having to be deleted from memory and added to memory 200 times a second.

The only other option I can think of is building an nginx module to run my app and forgoing lua entirely. Ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Use lua_nginx's built-in ngx.shared.DICT for fast in-memory storage.

From the [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.shared.DICT):

> The shared dictionary will retain its contents through a server config
>   reload (either by sending the HUP signal to the Nginx process or by
>   using the -s reload command-line option).
>
> The contents in the dictionary storage will be lost, however, when the
>   Nginx server quits.

Load your data from SQL into the shared dict, then use the shared dict from there.